# Does probability calibration always enhance the logloss?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, calibration, log-loss

I'm trying to calibrate some probabilities returned by different classifiers. I have plotted the `auc` and `logloss` of each one and I remark that the `logloss` is always improved (`auc` does not chance because I use monotonic function for the calibration).

Is there a result saying "that calibration always improve `logloss` score" or did I have those score enhancement by chance ?

Comment: Well, if your model optimizes logloss (e.g. logistic regression), then changing the solution makes logloss worse.

Comment: Seems legit indeed. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you know if all the models that optimizes logloss return well calibrated probabilities ?